# JavaScript Rock, Paper and Scissors always tie

Tags: javascript

Greeting all, I'm doing Odin Project and had rage quitted couple times without finding actual solution for this one. And finally after couple days I dedicated myself to post here for answer.
Maybe someone could explain where is a problem and why I get always output "It is tie" ?
Can't figure it out where is the problem.

```js
function compPlay() {
  const number = (Math.random() * 3);
  if (number <= 1) {
    return 'Rock';
  } else if (number >= 2) {
    return 'Paper';
  } else return 'Scissors';
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    return 'You Won ! Rock beats Scissors.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return 'You Lose ! Rock beats Scissors.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return 'You Won ! Paper beats Rock.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return 'You Lost ! Paper beats Rock.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return 'You Won ! Scissors beats Paper.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    return 'You Lost ! Scissors beats Paper.';
  } else {
    return 'It is tie';
  }
}

const playerSelection = window.prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors:");
const computerSelection = compPlay();

console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: `if (number <= 1) {` is true for 0 and 1. Convert `number` to an int then make your selection on `0, 1, or 2`

Comment: If your selection has different case (`Rock` rather than `rock`) or contains a leading or trailing space, the conditional statement will show a tie

Comment: Uhh.. case sensitive didn't though about it fixed with:
`const playerSelection = window.prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors:").toLowerCase();`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should update your compPlay function to round your number to whole numbers. Then you can do direct number comparisons and hit each case. You also need to trim any trailing whitespace and lower case your user input so your comparisons actually match up. I would also check explicitly for a tie by checking user input equals to computer input and dump anything else as no match.

```
function compPlay() {
  const number = Math.ceil((Math.random() * 3));
  if (number == 1) {
    return 'Rock';
  } else if (number == 2) {
    return 'Paper';
  } else return 'Scissors';
}

function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
  if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    return 'You Won ! Rock beats Scissors.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return 'You Lose ! Rock beats Scissors.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'Rock') {
    return 'You Won ! Paper beats Rock.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return 'You Lost ! Paper beats Rock.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'Paper') {
    return 'You Won ! Scissors beats Paper.';
  } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'Scissors') {
    return 'You Lost ! Scissors beats Paper.';
  } else if (playerSelection == computerSelection.toLowerCase()) {
    return 'It is tie';
  } else {
     return 'No Match'
  }
}

const playerSelection = (window.prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors:")).trim().toLowerCase();
const computerSelection = compPlay();

console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
```

Answer (score -1):

In the final `else`, print out `playerSelection` and `computerSelection` in quotes. It's most likely a case issue, but you can easily find out what you're comparing.

I'd also suggest modifying the logic a little to make it easier on yourself:

```
if(playerSelection === 'rock') {
    if(computerSelection === 'rock') {
        console.log('tie!');
    } else if(computerSelection === 'paper') {
        console.log('you lose!')
    } else if(computerSelection === 'scissors') {
        console.log('you win!');
    }
} else if(playerSelection === 'paper') {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

It's a little more verbose, but much easier to read and figure out what's going on.